# JBoss and Oracle Proxy Authentication

Tags: authentication, jpa, proxy, datasource

I would like to use ["Oracle Proxy Authentication"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Oracle/Proxy) in my web application. I'm using JPA framework for persistence and eclipselink as JPA provider.

The code I'm using is

```
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("eclipselink.oracle.proxy-type", oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME);
        properties.put(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_NAME, "egonzalez");
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.mode", "Always");
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.is-lazy", "false");       


        em = emf.createEntityManager(properties);
```

When I define the persistence unit without using a datasource, it works fine.

```
    <properties>                           
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.12.54.210:1523:dsr" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="unificado" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="asdas" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    </properties>
```

But when I define the persistent unit through a datasource, it doesn't work.

```
    <properties> 
        <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="com.ieci.mugeju.middleware.model.util.JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.OraclePlatform"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource" value="java:/OracleDS"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>  
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    </properties>
```

I'm working with JBoss 4.2.3.

Comment: what "doesn't work"? what error do you get (include stack)

Comment: I'm not getting any error. The database connection I'm getting belongs to the datasource user, and not to the "proxy user".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried what it is explained in a Olaf Heimburger's article: 
[Using Oracle Proxy Authentication with JPA (EclipseLink-Style)](https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/using_oracle_proxy_authenticat).
But I'm not sure why this solution doesn't work for me. I'm working with Oracle Dababase 10g, JBoss 7.1.1 and EclipseLink 2.5.1 provider, and the application architecture I've chosen is a JSF 2.0 web application with EJB injection and container-managed entity managers (transaction-scoped).

Because I've spent a lot of time looking for a Oracle Proxy Authentication solution, I'm going to explain what I've done.

I've defined and configured a SessionEventAdapter (org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.SessionEventAdapter) in my application.

```
public class ProxyAuthenticationSessionEventListener extends
    SessionEventAdapter
{   

  @Override
  public void postAcquireConnection(SessionEvent event)
  {
    DatabaseAccessor da = (DatabaseAccessor)event.getResult();

    OracleConnection oracleConn =  null;
    try
    {
      WrappedConnection wrappedConn = (WrappedConnection)  da.getConnection();
      Connection underlyingConn = wrappedConn.getUnderlyingConnection();        
      oracleConn = (OracleConnection)underlyingConn;
      if (!oracleConn.isProxySession())
      {
          java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
          prop.put(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_NAME, user);
          prop.put(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_PASSWORD, password);
          oracleConn.openProxySession(OracleConnection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME, prop);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                       
  }

  @Override
  public void preReleaseConnection(SessionEvent event)
  {
    DatabaseAccessor da = (DatabaseAccessor)event.getResult();

    OracleConnection oracleConn =  null;
    try
    {
      WrappedConnection wrappedConn = (WrappedConnection)  da.getConnection();
      Connection underlyingConn = wrappedConn.getUnderlyingConnection();        
      oracleConn = (OracleConnection)underlyingConn;

      if (oracleConn.isProxySession())
      {
        oracleConn.close(OracleConnection.PROXY_SESSION);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
  }
}
```

User and password could be received in the SessionEventAdapter through ThreadLocal.

In persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="eclipselink.session-event-listener" value="example.ProxyAuthenticationSessionEventListener"/>
```

This solution is based on getting the Oracle connection through the JBoss wrapped connection, so I also need to configure some dependencies in my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment> 
 <dependencies> 
    <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />  
    <module name="com.oracle.ojdbc6" />
 </dependencies>
 <exclusions>
   <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
 </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters is the module with the JBOSS library that contains the wrapped connections classes.

I really hope this answer help somebody.